# Regex matches extra character

Tags: regex

I want to match only "A" and exclude "xyz":

```
ABC xyz
```

But using

```
A[^xyz]
```

It matches

```
AB
```

Edit: I know the example doesn't make much sense (If I only wanted to match `A`, I would just use `A` as the regex. But it illustrates the problem I'm having, where whenever I add a matching pattern followed by an exclusion pattern in the form of `[^xyz]`, the matching pattern always seems to match an extra unwanted character, (`B` in this example.)

Comment: `B` is not `x` nor `y` nor `z`; `[^xyz]` matches `B`. Why don't you just use `A` ?

Comment: You can check using for example: http://www.regexpal.com (very useful for finding bugs in regex)

Comment: Do you want it to match any `A`, an `A` followed by `BC`, an `A` followed by `BC xyz`, an `A` that is not followed by `xyz` or something else? Please give more examples of what you want to extract, and what you want to extract from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A[^xyz]` matches `A*` where `*` is any character that in *not* x, y, or z.
See this page for more information: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated

If you want to match any `A` in any string, use the regex `A`. I think what you are looking for, though, is an `A` that is not followed by `xyz`. To do this, use the regex [`A(?!xyz)`](http://regex101.com/r/fA4tA5), which implements a [Negative Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: If that were the case, woudln't it also match "ABC"? Right now it only matches "AB".

Comment: `[^xyz]` matches a _single_ character that is not `x`, `y`, or `z`.

Comment: Ok that first page you linked explains it, A[^xyz] means A followed by any character that is NOT "xyz".

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to match a single `A`, that's what your regex should be.

```
A
```

It looks like you're trying to say "match an A that isn't an x, y or z" which is of course redundant.

Comment: Sorry I thought that was evident, I added the clarification on the original post.

Comment: So what *are* you trying to match here?